# How to paint on previous picture in the functional way in Racket

Tags: racket

This code maintains number of ticks, but all ways paints on a new screen

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/universe)
(require 2htdp/image)
(define pasaulis (empty-scene 100 100))

(define (trace-circle t)
  (place-image (circle 5 "solid" "blue")
                   (+ 50(* 40 (cos (/ t 100))))
                   (+ 50(* 40 (sin (/ t 100))))
                   pasaulis))

(define (render t)
  (text (number->string t) 12 "red"))

(big-bang 1000000
      (on-tick sub1 1/500)
      (to-draw trace-circle)
      (stop-when zero?)
      (record? true))
```

The following code does maintain picture, but I could not have number of ticks passed to the pain handler.

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/universe)
(require 2htdp/image)
(require picturing-programs)

(define (move-right-10 picture)
  (beside (rectangle 10 0 "solid" "white")
      picture))

(big-bang pic:calendar
      (on-draw show-it 500 100)
      (on-tick move-right-10 1/22))
```

I just cannot figure it out. how to have draw function with number of ticks, while modifying the screen. Is the big-bang function suitable at all for the purpose?

Comment: If you need to keep track of two things at once (both ticks and the picture) then you can store them in a struct. For example: (define-struct state (pic ticks))

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/universe)
(require 2htdp/image)

(struct world (ticks pic))

(define pasaulis (empty-scene 1000 1000))

(define (render w)
  (world-pic w))

(define (handle-on-tick w)
  (define t (world-ticks w))
  (define p (world-pic w))
  (define new-ticks (+ t 1))
  (define new-pic (overlay/xy (text (number->string t) 12 "red")
                              (* -10 t) (* -10 t)
                              p))
  (world new-ticks new-pic))


(define (stop? w)
  (= (world-ticks w) 50))

(big-bang (world 0    pasaulis)
          (on-tick    handle-on-tick 1/5)
          (to-draw    render)
          (stop-when  stop?))
```